# index, acronym and sorting, macro expansion

Tags: macros, indexing, expansion, acronyms

I want to use index together with acro: Whenever I use an acronym, I want it automatically in the index. However, not the abbreviation but the long name!

What I did: I created a new command:

```
\newcommand{\acidx}[1]{\ac{#1}\index{\acl*{#1}}}
```

This works. However, latex does not expand the acl macro **before** writing the ind file! Mixing `index` and acidx` the contents of the idx file is:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \item \texttt  {\acl *{ABC}}, \hyperpage{2}
  \item \texttt  {\acl *{DEF}}, \hyperpage{1, 2}
  \indexspace
  \item consetetur, \hyperpage{1}
\end{theindex}
```

It can be seen that the elements from `acidx` are grouped together. I assume because `\acl` was not expanded. If it had, it would be properly sorted.

To alleviate the issue, I tried

```
\newcommand{\acidx}[1]{\ac{#1}\index{#1@\acl*{#1}}}
```

However, this is not quite clean because (to my understanding), the index is now sorted according to the abbreviation rather than the full name, e.g. for PHP it would be sorted according to PHP rather than "Hypertext Preprocessor".
Furthermore, when doing this, every entry is separated by `\indexspace` which is also not correct.

Is there  a way to force index to expand the macro before writing the ind file?

Is there another way to fix the problem?

I would really like to avoid using a different index processor like xindy!

Comment: Could you add a small example of a document to play with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Package `acronym`

The internal expandable version of `\acl` is `\AC@acl`. Then `\index` inside the macro `\acidx` will write the expanded long version of the acronym:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\acidx}[1]{%
  \ac{#1}\index{\AC@acl{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\acrodef{ABC}{alphabet}
\acrodef{DEF}{definition}

\begin{document}

The \acidx{ABC} contains all\index{all} letters. The \acidx{DEF}
is written with the help of the \acidx{ABC}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]

And the index:

> [image: Page 2]

The `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{alphabet}{1}
\indexentry{all}{1}
\indexentry{definition}{1}
\indexentry{alphabet}{1}
```

## Package `acro`

The same with package `acro`, which is based on LaTeX3.
`\prop_get:NnNF` gets the property `\l__acro_long_prop` from the data list for acronym id `#1` and stores the result in `\l__acro_long_tl`, see the definition of `\acro_get:n`). The result token list variable `\l__acro_long_tl` can then be used in `\index`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*{\acidx}[1]{%
  \ac{#1}%
  \prop_get:NnNF \l__acro_long_prop {#1} \l__acro_long_tl {}
  \index{\l__acro_long_tl}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcronym{ABC}{short=ABC, long=alphabet}
\DeclareAcronym{DEF}{short=DEF, long=definition}

\begin{document}

The \acidx{ABC} contains all\index{all} letters. The \acidx{DEF}
is written with the help of the \acidx{ABC}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP is using `acro`, not `acronym`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the hint. I have now also added a version for package `acro`.

Comment: While the `acro` version works, you're using “private“ macros (with `__`), which is a “don't do it” according to the guidelines. This should be a feature request to the package author.

Comment: I am using acronym (not acro) but great explanation which is very helpful. I adjusted the title.